# Can I attach a noticeboard to a plasterboard wall using superglue?

Tags: drywall, adhesive

I would like to put up a cork noticeboard (with wooden frame) in my kitchen, but the location I want it has several wires and pipes behind it and I am very wary of drilling into it. So I'm looking for a noninvasive method of attachment.

As the noticeboard is fairly light (and would only have paper pinned to it), is superglue an option? The idea is to glue along the wooden edge of the board and press it against the wall for 24 hours.

While the glue is very strong I'm not so sure about the paint on the wall. Might the board rip the paint off the wall? All in all, is this a viable solution (and if not what do you think my options are?)

Comment: Super glue is not the glue you're looking for.  There are far better ways to attach the board to the wall, but if you *really* want to use glue, construction adhesive is probably the way to go.  You'll likely only need a dab at each corner, though you will have to hold the board in place until the adhesive starts to grab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superglue will not fill the voids well enough between the wall and the wood frame. There are picture hooks with a special adhesive that may work for your purpose. [See here, there is a variety on this link](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=command%20hooks&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=32825864549&hvpos=1t2&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13653450586426242697&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_1gfgp1badb_b)

Comment: Thank you 3M, not sure how we hung light weight stuff on walls before you came around.

Comment: Worked perfectly.